# HTML Content to List

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, data-science

I would like to read all the content from an html page and have this stored in a list.

Could you pls suggest options in Python

For Example:

url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_of_Germany

Get all the content from this page and store this in a list

The Chancellor of Germany is the head of government of Germany. The official title in German is Bundeskanzler(in) (literally, Federal Chancellor), sometimes shortened to Kanzler(in). The term, dating from the early Middle Ages, is derived from the Latin term cancellarius.
In German politics, the Chancellor is equivalent to that of a prime minister in many other countries. German has two equivalent translations of prime minister, Premierminister and Ministerpräsident. While Premierminister usually refers to heads of governments of foreign countries (e.g., the United Kingdom), Ministerpräsident may also refer to the heads of government of most German states.
The current Chancellor is Angela Merkel, who is serving her third term in office. She is the first female chancellor, thus being known in German as Bundeskanzlerin (that particular word was never used officially before Merkel, but it is a grammatically regular formation of a noun denoting a female chancellor, adding "-in" to the end of "Bundeskanzler").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple:

```
import requests
import bs4

response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_of_Germany')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
txt = soup.find("div", {"id": "mw-content-text"})
para = txt.findAll('p')

for item in para:
    print item.text
```

You can print this or store that on the list or anything else. Also, you can `tokenize` that with `nltk` base on sentences.